# Data Annotations - Not Zero

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, data-annotations, wcf-ria-services

How do you annotate a numerical field that is required, and must not zero....  I have tried looking this up a couple of times, but can't find anything on it.  Surely  I can't be alone!

[Range(-9999999,-1)] is good for negative values only (is there a better way?)

OK - so how about NOT zero?

Range(1,9999999) and Range(-9999999,-1) - but two range attributes is incorrect.  Is Custom attribute the only way to go?

Regards,
R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this using the standard validation attributes. As you say, you could use a custom attribute. Alternatively you could use someone else's library, for example [MVC Foolproof validation](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) appears to provide a NotEqualTo operator which you could use.

Comment: It's pretty easy to write your own custom validation. Jeff has a post that explains how to do it. http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/09/26/RiaServicesCustomReusableValidators.aspx